# Admin page loads too slow when using inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an inline in my model admin class:

```
class LogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [LogExerciseInline]
```

and here's what this inline class looks like:

```
class LogExerciseInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = LogExercise
    ordering = ['order']
    extra = 0
```

It takes around 50 seconds to load admin change form on my machine for an object with only three related `LogExercise`'s. And if I remove `inlines` field from `LogAdmin` class, it takes only 2 seconds to load the page.

I tried to use Django Debug Toolbar to get some details about it, but it adds too much overhead, so it takes minutes to load just one page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't mention one thing: `LogExercise` model has `exercise` field that is FK to another model. So all I needed to do was to add `raw_id_fields` to my `LogExerciseInline`:

```
raw_id_fields = ('exercise',)
```